# Concatenating and pasting two columns using line breaks within data-frame/data.table

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation, paste

This is what my dataframe looks like

```
library(data.table)

    dt <- fread('
       Batch   Score   Type       Description
        A          1   fruit         apple 
        A          2   beverage      pepsi 
        A          3   food          rice
        B          1   beverage      coke
        B          2   fruit         banana
        C          1   food          butter
        D          1   food          bread 
    ')
```

Once I identify the row where a particular batch has the highest Score, I want to concatenate `Type` and `Description` and paste them all the way(all the elements from the first row to the last row with the highest Score) using **line breaks** and **gap** between Type and Description. The pasting is done  upto the row with the highest score for that batch so that it looks like the following:

```
Batch   Score(Max)        Description2
    A          3        fruit     apple
                        beverage  pepsi
                        food      rice                          
    B          2        beverage  coke
                        fruit     banana                     
    C          1        food      butter
    D          1        food      bread
```

The row with the highest score for the batch also happens to be the last row for that batch in my dataframe. I have tried:

```
dt[, .(MaxScore = max(Score), 
Description2 = cat(paste(Type, Description), sep="\n")),by = .(Batch)]
```

The goal is to show all that information in one column(Description2) and one row for each batch.Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: This does not fully answer the OP's question.*

---

I do something similar (but not exactly the same):

```
print(x=dt[,{
mx = max(Score)

subdat = .SD[, !"Score", with=FALSE]
newrow0 = lapply(subdat, function(x) as("",class(x)))
newrow  = newrow0
newrow[length(newrow)] = paste0(" Max Score: ", mx)
rbind(
  subdat, 
  newrow,
  newrow0
)
}, by=Batch], nrows=Inf, row.names=FALSE)
```

which gives

```
 Batch     Type   Description
     A    fruit         apple
     A beverage         pepsi
     A     food          rice
     A           Max Score: 3
     A                       
     B beverage          coke
     B    fruit        banana
     B           Max Score: 2
     B                       
     C     food        butter
     C           Max Score: 1
     C                       
     D     food         bread
     D           Max Score: 1
     D
```

I just use this to review the data in the console. I put the metadata for the group on a row instead of a column because I have enough columns to nearly span the screen already.

Note that the `as("", class(x))` is very unreliable (e.g., not working with `Date` class). It might be necessary to just coerce the entire table to string first.

---

For printing multiple columns as one, use `sprintf`:

```
print(x=dt[,{
mx = max(Score)
subdat = .(
  Description = as.character(Description), 
  Type = as.character(Type)
)
.(mx, sprintf("%10s %15s", subdat$Type, subdat$Description))
}, by=Batch], nrows=Inf, row.names=FALSE)

 Batch V1                         V2
     A  3      fruit           apple
     A  3   beverage           pepsi
     A  3       food            rice
     B  2   beverage            coke
     B  2      fruit          banana
     C  1       food          butter
     D  1       food           bread
```

This is very manual but it should be obvious how it can be done more programmatically, starting with `sapply(dt, function(x) max(nchar(x)))`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Frank. The reason I am trying to stuff all that information in one column(Description2) is that I am trying to export that field to salesforce. Salesforce reporting is quite bad and it does not play nice with data that is outside its sphere. By creating one field, I was thinking about displaying all that information in a readable format while making it feasible to upload it to salesforce.

Comment: Hey Frank, how do I coerce your output to a dataframe? And how can I take out the Max Score from the final output, I dont need that part.

Comment: @gibbz The "max score" part shows up in `newrow`, so exclude that part from the final `rbind`. Just use `as.data.frame` if you want a data.frame. You mentioned newlines, etc., which made it sound to me like you were after text output, maybe importing with fwf.

Comment: I edited the original post. I hope it makes it easier to arrive at the desired output.

Comment: @gibbz My approach cannot create the blank values under each Batch. I'm considering deleting, since I don't have much interest in exploring other ways of printing and so won't be answering the question fully here.

Comment: I totally understand. Thank you for all your help!